# AngularJS - calculator page- multiple properties multiplied together

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm working on a cost-calculator page that has a carousel to allow people to select an item that has a price.

Then, that price will have another selector for times per month.

So, a total cost would be price * times per month (tpm).

If I put this into the page it's {{ price * tpm}}.

I'm OK with this implementation method, if it were just these two variables, but this is actually a future price calculator.  There are also two extra properties in play:  years and interest rate.

So, the actual calculation would be:  (((price * tpm) * 12) * years) * %.

I really don't want to have this in the page.  I'd much rather put the calculations in the model and just show the final, calculated result in the view html.

My application is pretty complicated, layout-wise, but I've put up a little fiddle to demonstrate the logic.

http://jsfiddle.net/scott_in_ct/SPN8V/

```
$scope.$watch(
    function(){
        return $scope.price * $scope.item1TPM * $scope.years * $scope.int;
    }, 
    function(newVal, oldVal) {
        $scope.total = $scope.price * $scope.item1TPM * 12;
        $scope.totalOverTime = $scope.price * $scope.item1TPM * $scope.years * $scope.int;
});
```

The problem I just realized I'm having is that if the fields are grouped with a wrapper that is using an ng-if to show/hide their contents, the results are not consistent.

-- Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit about the `ng-if`:

Be careful with `ng-if`. It totally removes the nodes from the DOM tree. So they do not exist at all. Often it is something you want. But often `ng-show` is the way to go. In your case if you tracked the issue to `ng-if`, then `ng-show` should probably fix things for you.

If you  do not want to fiddle with watches and the calculation itself is not expensive you can use function binding.

declare function on scope like this:

```
$scope.calculatePrice = function (){
return  (((price * tpm) * 12) * years) * %;//here your calculation that makes sense in controller context
};
```

then bind it in html like that

```
<div>{{calcualetPrice()}}</div>
```

Be warned that function binding can be evaluated many times, but it saves you the headache of finetuning the watches etc. Anytime variables used in the function expression change the value should be refreshed. And then some more.